# Banach space for Frobenius norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I want to prove that  $(\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbf{R}), ||.||_F)$ is a Banach Space

where
$A \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbf{R})$, the Frobenius norm:

$$
||A||_F = \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}^{2} } 
$$

I attempted to redefine the matrix $A$ into linear mapping $T: \mathbf{R}^{n} \to \mathbf{R}^{m}$, where $T(x) = Ax$ for $x \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$.

I am stuck on showing a Cauchy Sequence $(T_n) \subset \mathbf{R}^{m}$ is converging to $T$ with respect to the norm $ ||. ||_F$ . How should I go from this approach or any suggestion differently?

Comment: Can you use the Cauchiness to show that each entry must be a Cauchy sequence of reals and hence must converge?

Comment: I see. I think the Cauchiness way would make this one easier to see than linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

So, should I define the Cauchy sequence of matrices in this way:

$$
A^{(n)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{11}^{(n)} & \dots  & x_{1n}^{(n)} \\
    \vdots & \vdots  \\
    x_{m1}^{(n)} & \dots  & x_{mn}^{(n)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where each entries in these matrices are Cauchy Sequence. By Classical Convergence Cauchy criterion in $\mathbf{R}$, it converges. So the Cauchy sequence of matrices converge to $A$ with respect to $||.||_F$.